# How to do time-to-event analysis?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Let's assume I have a data showing time-to progression, where 'time' represents the follow-up time, progress=1 means progress while 2 means censored, how can I perform a time-to progression analysis in r? `surv` in r can only provide survival analysis

| time | progress |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

Comment: This sounds like a question for CrossValidated https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks! Will try that

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing particularly special about survival. It's just a dichotomous outcome with an associated duration of exposure to the risk of the particular event's occurrence. What is called "survival analysis" by some is called "event history analysis" by others. Engineers do analyses of "MTTB", i.e mean time to breakdown, which is really the same as a calculation of life expectancy. Each use the same sorts of mathematical machinery to handle time-to-events when some of the times represent duration of exposure without event. Your data should be easily handled by the functions in the standard `survival` package or you can use one of the other packages such as `eha` or `rms` that have methods for handling censored event-time data. There's even a full CRAN Task View. From the help page for the `Surv` function (not `surv` since that function is capitalized.)

```
library(survival)
?Surv
```

`event   The status indicator, normally 0=alive, 1=dead. Other choices are TRUE/FALSE (TRUE = death) or 1/2 (2=death).`

So you would need to recode your 1/2 variable so that the 2 represented the event mark.

Comment: sorry, I'm quite now to survival analysis, I'm using survfit() to fit the kaplan meier curve, and plotted the time-to-desease progression curve using ggsurvplot(fun='event'), and my question is is there a way to calculate the pr(desease progress in 5 years) and its 95%CI?

Comment: I’m pretty sure that’s been asked and answered before. If you have done a good faith search and come up empty, then edit your question with specifics like data and code executed so far and be sure to include the search terms that were not successful.